# How to prevent Grid's children from scaling?

Tags: c#, wpf

The `ItemsControl` is scaled using `Slider`. The problem is that the `Thumb`s and `BorderThickness` are scaled in the way that the `BorderThickness` become too thin and almost not visible or too thick. The same is with `Thumb`s.

How to prevent `Thumb` and `BorderThickness` from scaling while still allowing `Grid` to scale?

I thought maybe to use a `Converter` that will rescale `Border`'s thickness 
`BorderThickness="{Binding ElementName=MyItemsControl, Converter={StaticResource descaleConverter}}"`
but the `Converter` is applied only once and not called more when `ItemsControl` is being scaled.

Any ideas?

```
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Segments}" x:Name="MyItemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform 
                    ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=scaleSlider,Path=Value}" />
            </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="{Binding Duration}" Height="100">
                        <Grid Opacity="0">
                            <local:ResizeThumb Height="6" Cursor="SizeNS" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            <local:ResizeThumb Width="6" Cursor="SizeWE" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <local:ResizeThumb Width="6" Cursor="SizeWE" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
                            <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    <Slider
        x:Name="scaleSlider"            
        Value="1" Minimum="0.01" Maximum="4"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe applying the inverse transform to the child grids of the DataTemplate will do what you want, or hopefully point you in the right direction.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Width="{Binding Duration}" Height="100">
        <Grid Opacity="0" LayoutTransform="{Binding ElementName=MyItemsControl, Path=LayoutTransform.Inverse}">
            <local:ResizeThumb Height="6" Cursor="SizeNS" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <local:ResizeThumb Width="6" Cursor="SizeWE" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <local:ResizeThumb Width="6" Cursor="SizeWE" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
         </Grid>
         <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False"
               LayoutTransform="{Binding ElementName=MyItemsControl, Path=LayoutTransform.Inverse}">
             <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" />
         </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```